# How to draw numbers from a new line?

Tags: python

there is a code with prime numbers (which are displayed in the desired range)

1. Make simple numbers appear on the new line.

Here is the code:

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
ls = []
for i in range(a, b + 1):
 if all(i % n != 0 for n in range(2, i)):
   ls.append(str(i))
 if len(ls):
   print(' '.join(ls))
 else:
   print(0)
```

Comment: Then what is your question, I mean, what are you having difficulties with?

Comment: maybe add a line break: `print('\n'.join(ls))`

Comment: @abdusco I pointed out above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a loop for print the result

```
print('= Enter the range (a,b) =')
a, b = map(int, input().split())
ls = []
for i in range(a, b + 1):
 if all(i % n != 0 for n in range(2, i)): # check the numbers
   ls.append(str(i))

print('========= Result ========')
#print the result
for number in ls:
    print(number)

print('========== End ==========')
```